# How to avoid invalid errors when comparing integers with explicit collation in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, utf8mb4

Okay, not the clearest title ever; feel free to improve.

I have a table representing thousands of linguistic forms. Many of these make heavy use of diacritics, so all of *aha*, *áha̱* and *ā̧́ḫà̀* may appear. The table (and the database) uses UTF-8 as character set and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` as the default collation scheme, since searching should be case- and diacritic-agnostic (so searching for *aha* should bring up all three). These forms have all been entered in manually by human beings, though, so there are inevitably duplicates.

I’m currently trying to get a list of exactly identical forms in order to get rid of duplicates (manually – each token would have to be checked before being removed), but in this case I need to search in a diacritic-aware manner – that is, given the three tokens listed above, I would expect a search to yield no results, since they are three different forms because of the diacritics.

I figured this should be a fairly easy task; just do:

```
SELECT token FROM table GROUP BY token HAVING COUNT(token) > 1 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

But alas, that does not work. Instead, it gives me an error message that “COLLATION utf8mb4_bin is not valid for CHARACTER SET latin1”. I should note that I have absolutely nothing Latin-1 anywhere – no character sets, no collations, no server charsets, nothing. There are also no stored procedures or anything else where Latin-1 might creep in.

No, this is because of [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73858), which is apparently fixed from 5.7 onwards; see the description at the bottom:

> For constructs such as ORDER BY numeric_expr COLLATE collation_name, the character set of the expression was treated as latin1, which resulted in an error if the collation specified after COLLATE is incompatible with latin1. Now when a numeric expression is implicitly cast to a character expression in the presence of COLLATE, the character set used is the one associated with the named collation.

Unfortunately, I’m on 5.6, and I don’t have the option of upgrading (annoyingly). Converting the data to Latin-1 is also not an option, nor is changing the collation on the table.

Is there a way to run my query or an equivalent one yielding the result set I’m after, without getting the collation error?

Comment: You could use [HEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/hexadecimal-literals.html), so `select token from table group by hex(token) having count(*)>1`

Comment: @Luuk Clever! As a workaround, I’d simply duplicated the table and changed the collation scheme on the duplicate, but that doesn’t work if you want it to be more than a one-off, and preferably this should be user-initiable, so that an admin can remove duplicates through a web interface.

Comment: I don't see a numeric_expr; is that SELECT missing something?

Comment: Many characters would probably be unavailable in latin1.  Sticking a COLLATE clause on is a possibility.  Luuk's suggestion is _probably_ equivalent to `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` should be the same as `COUNT(token)`.  Can you provide a self-contained test case that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @RickJames The numeric expression is `COUNT(*) > 1` (doesn’t matter whether it’s counting `*` or `token`). I’m not sure why, but the result of `COUNT()` (which is an integer) for some reason gets converted to a string somewhere along the line, and up until 5.6, that conversion always happened with charset Latin-1, regardless of context charset or collation. At its base, according to the bug log, a simple `SELECT 2 > 1 COLLATE utf8_bin` will trigger the bug.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677662/why-am-i-seeing-collation-xxx-is-not-valid-for-character-set-yyy/28932003?noredirect=1#comment113587223_28932003

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
CREATE TABLE x(s VARCHAR(11) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO x (s)
    VALUES ('aha'), ('áha̱'), ('ā̧́ḫà̀'),
    ('i'), ('i̯');
SELECT s FROM x GROUP BY s HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comes back with

aha
i

without any complaints about numeric stuff.

I ran it on 5.6.46, 5.7.26, 8.0.16 and several MariaDB versions.

What I am doing differently than your case?

When adding an explicate `COLLATE` clause, put it on the component of the query that needs it.  (`COLLATE` does not apply to the query as a whole; different parts can be collated differently.)

Comment: You’re not explicitly collating in the `SELECT` statement – for whatever reason, that seems to be what makes the difference. My tables have `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` as their collation because that’s what they normally need; needing `utf8mb4_bin` is more of a one-off (or at least rarer) need, so I can’t simply set the table to have the right collation before the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Oh bugger. I just realised that I did leave something out of the query in the question – I forgot the explicit collation! Added in now.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Add to `COLLATE` clause to the part you want collated -- not the `HAVING COUNT(token) > 1`.

Comment: Oh, I thought `COLLATE` applied to the statement as a whole. Didn’t realise you could apply it to individual parts!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Ok, I added to my Answer.